# Nav bar colour not as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am having issues with my nav bar on my website. I want to make it red with a light red hover effect but for some reason it is coming out red and black.

How can I fix the colours?

[image: This is what I'm seeing]

```css
.navbar-inverse {
     background-color: #cc0001;
     
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
       <a href="index.html"><img src="..\images\rpm.png" id="logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
  
        
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What do you need to keep in mind?**

- Since, you're using bootstrap the default bootstrap.css is being applied to your navbar-nav buttons so make sure you add the **!important** add the end of each of your custom css to make it applied.
- *Remove **"active"** class from the other list items except home*. That is the *reason why each of them has a **black background** by default*.
- You can add a custom light backgrond on hover using .`navbar-nav li:hover` as described below.
- **Bonus:** If you want the *active class to not be black* either or some shade of red, you can *implement a background color for it* as well using `.navbar-nav li.active a`.

```css
.navbar-inverse {
     background-color: #cc0001 !important;  
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover{
background-color: #ff3232 !important;
color:white;
}

.navbar-nav li.active a{
background-color: #ff0000 !important;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
       <a href="index.html"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" id="logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>   
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I'm just recently getting to grips with the whole bootstrap thing and this had helped me a lot with my learning i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a:hover{} to give the hover effect.

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #f50c0c  !important;
  border-color: #080808;
}
.active a:hover {
    background-color: pink !important;
}
.nav li a{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
       <a href="index.html"><img src="..\images\rpm.png" id="logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
  
        
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This isn't helpful and solve the other problems OP has mentioned.

Comment: Check out the marked answer, you will come to know that there is the same css has been applied.

Comment: So there is a humble request @Highdef to you that check the soltion first and then give vote.

Comment: @Khushbhu Do you know what bootstrap is? If you had imported the required files with the CSS you provided, the output won't be what you see there right now. And the marked answer is mine itself, if you see the differences there are.

Comment: yes but it's not what he wanted, whatever he wanted was there in my answer and you just can't say that my answer is not helpful so why to downvote? a big disappointment @Highdef :/

Comment: Since, you're so stuck at this thing and not trying to really understand the reason for the downvote, I'll retract that thing (you'll have to make an edit) but if I hadn't downvoted now, you'll soon see other downvotes again and again when you answer other posts. What you lack in this answer? 1. It's not your intention, because everyone here is trying to help. 2. People don't care if you're trying to help or not, they care if you're trying to provide exactly what the OP requires.

Comment: 3. You have not even explained anything "You should use a:hover{} to give the hover effect."  This is SO , it's not just about what you do now but for the future visitors to see, do you think they'll understand what the problem is and has been solved by just that line? Most won't. 4. Downvotes should help you realize what you've done wrong and try to improve on it, rather than being stuck on it that you shouldn't have been.
If you didn't learn anything from this, you can try to see how I answer, how many other people try to answer for future readers.It helps you grow and get better.